# Flex, picture and scroll position

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

In the snippet below there are two images shown alternatingly. Those images are in a container that has `flex` set and each is wrapped in a `picture` tag.

Initially everything works, but when you scroll down slowly you will notice that as soon as you scroll past the edge of the image, the following text starts jumping around.

This doesn't happen if I remove the `picture` tags.

What's going on here?

```js
window.setInterval(function () {
  document.querySelector('.a').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.b').style.display = 'inline-block';
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector('.a').style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.querySelector('.b').style.display = 'none';
  }, 500);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p style="height: 100px;"></p>
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; height: 200px;">
  <picture>
    <img class="a" src="https://placekitten.com/g/300/200">
  </picture>
  <picture>
    <img class="b" src="https://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </picture>
</div>
Meow
<p style="height: 3000px;"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of toggling the display which will affect the height of the layout creating the flicker, make the width to be 0 instead

```js
window.setInterval(function () {
  document.querySelector('.a').style.width = 0;
  document.querySelector('.b').style.width = 'auto';
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector('.a').style.width = 'auto';
    document.querySelector('.b').style.width = 0;
  }, 500);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p style="height: 100px;"></p>
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
  <picture>
    <img class="a" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
  </picture>
  <picture>
    <img class="b" src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
  </picture>
</div>
Meow
<p style="height: 3000px;"></p>
```

Comment: I don't think this has to do with height. To show that, I added a fixed height to the container element in my question.

Comment: @AndreKR it still changes the height of other elements (pictures) and affecting the general layout. add fixed height to picture too and you won't see the flicker